# Error when loading the SDK - something related to Enumeration

Tags: android, eclipse

Team,

I've been using Eclipse and AVDs and also GenyMotion since couple of months without any issues but since yes'day, I've seeing this error message for AVDs whenever I restart the Eclipse. FYI - My config is Win7 -64 bit

I already tried deleted the existing AVDs, recreating those again and also restarted the Eclipse multiple times but it is showing the same error message.

Even though till now I didn't notice any functional issues with the AVDs for running my Apps or even on my actual device but wanted to ensure to understand what went wrong and how can I overcome this error message.

I'm attaching a screen-shot for your reference and also the `'devices.xml'` file below from the location `C:\Users\RAMA\.android/devices.xml'`. I tried to find the solution in SO and also over the other places but couldn't quite get to the bottom of the solution

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       -<d:devices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/devices/1">
       -<d:device>
        <d:name>NexusSS_AVD19</d:name>
        <d:manufacturer>User</d:manufacturer>
        <d:meta/>
        -<d:hardware>
        -<d:screen>
        <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
        <d:diagonal-length>40.00</d:diagonal-length>
        <d:pixel-density>nodpi</d:pixel-density>
        <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
        -<d:dimensions>
        <d:x-dimension>480</d:x-dimension>
        <d:y-dimension>800</d:y-dimension>
        </d:dimensions>
        <d:xdpi>23.32</d:xdpi>
        <d:ydpi>23.32</d:ydpi>
    -<d:touch>
        <d:multitouch>jazz-hands</d:multitouch>
        <d:mechanism>finger</d:mechanism>
        <d:screen-type>capacitive</d:screen-type>
    </d:touch>
    </d:screen>
        <d:networking> Bluetooth Wifi NFC</d:networking>
        <d:sensors> Accelerometer Barometer Compass GPS Gyroscope LightSensor ProximitySensor</d:sensors>
        <d:mic>true</d:mic>
        -<d:camera>
        <d:location>front</d:location>
        <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
        <d:flash>true</d:flash>
        </d:camera>
        -<d:camera>
        <d:location>back</d:location>
        <d:autofocus>true</d:autofocus>
        <d:flash>true</d:flash>
        </d:camera>
        <d:keyboard>qwerty</d:keyboard>
        <d:nav>dpad</d:nav>
        <d:ram unit="MiB">768</d:ram>
        <d:buttons>soft</d:buttons>
        <d:internal-storage unit="GiB"> 4</d:internal-storage>
        <d:removable-storage unit="TiB"/>
        <d:cpu>Generic CPU</d:cpu>
        <d:gpu>Generic GPU</d:gpu>
        <d:abi> armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips</d:abi>
        <d:dock/>
        <d:power-type>battery</d:power-type>
        </d:hardware>
    -<d:software>
    <d:api-level>-</d:api-level>
    <d:live-wallpaper-support>true</d:live-wallpaper-support>
    <d:bluetooth-profiles/>
    <d:gl-version>2.0</d:gl-version>
    <d:gl-extensions/>
    <d:status-bar>false</d:status-bar>
    </d:software>
    -<d:state name="Portrait" default="true">
    <d:description>The device in portrait orientation</d:description>
    <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
    <d:keyboard-state>keyshidden</d:keyboard-state>
    <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    -<d:state name="Landscape">
    <d:description>The device in landscape orientation</d:description>
    <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
    <d:keyboard-state>keyshidden</d:keyboard-state>
    <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    -<d:state name="Portrait with keyboard">
    <d:description>The device in portrait orientation with a keyboard open</d:description>
    <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
    <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
    <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    -<d:state name="Landscape with keyboard">
    <d:description>The device in landscape orientation with a keyboard open</d:description>
    <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
    <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
    <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
    </d:state>
    </d:device>
    </d:devices>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending good amount of time and looking all over the internet for the resolution really nothing helped me and unfortunately, even from SO no one responded for this typical / abnormal issue or behavior

I spend good couple of days time in researching for this and what is the cause of the issue and has been trying all ways like below steps by steps to get rid of the issue.

- I deleted all the AVDs and created them fresh again from scratch but NO USE
- I restarted the Eclipse multiple times and even system reboots as well but NO USE
- Finally, I looked in to `'devices.xml'` in the path `'C:\Users\RAMA\.android'` and went through line by line to see if i can catch something out of it but NOT REALLY ANYTHING MEANINGFUL
- Lastly, I decided to

  - DELETE all the AVDs again
  - DELETE the existing `'devices.xml'` from the path `'C:\Users\RAMA\.android'`
  - REBOOT THE SYSTEM AND RESTARTED THE ECLIPSE
  - Fortunately, no error seen during booting of Eclipse this time.
  - Then, created my AVDs again and started using them

NOW, IT IS WORKING SMOOTHLY WITHOUT ANY ISSUES OR ERROR MESSAGES.

I'll keep updating this in case if any issue encounters in future and wanted to post this as answer cause someone could get in to the same situations anytime...so my response could help the users in someways...

Answer (score 0):

Open sdk manager and delete all the packages from android 5.1.1(api 22) EXCEPT FOR 
a)documentation for android sdk
(b) sdk platform
 (c) samples for sdk
 (d)ARM EABI v7a system Image
(e)google apis
(f)Sources for android sdk. 
Then restart eclipse and clean the project and run.